# Windows Phone 8.1 displaying Azure data on listview

Tags: xaml, azure, windows-phone, azure-mobile-services

I'm facing some issues with displaying data on a listview in my WindowsApp 8.1 mobile. There is a table in my Azure Mobile Service called **SugarControler** which is the same name for a class that handles the data. which stores some data and has a column called **"Level".** When I'm trying to display data from that column in my app, I don't get data from that column, but instead every record displayed in the ListView is **MyApp.Controlers.SugarControler**. What am I missing here?

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        ...
        <ListView Name="ListItems" Margin="0,9.5,-0.167,10" Grid.Row="4">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="cell">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Level}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.Resources>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

From the backend site everything seems to be ok, as I can add a new data into the database from the UI and it is displayed properly in the Azure database.